# How to make a loop if the Sheets is empty and do not copy anything?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cvs file that sometimes contains no data, I extract it in Excel but the loop I want to do is: If the sheet "temp is empty" I want to copy nothing?

```
 Sub StartExtract()

 ' Set the sid and client to connect to
   W_System = "P10320"
 ' Run the GUI script
  RunGUIScript
 ' End the GUI session
  objSess.EndTransaction
 'effacer contenu feuille temp
  Sheets("temp").Select
  Cells.Select
  Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
 'Switch to the worksheet where the data is loaded to
  Sheets("temp").Select

  'Load the CSV file
  OpenCSVFile

  Sheets("BGSOCIAL").Select
  Columns("B:G").Select
  Selection.ClearContents
  Sheets("temp").Range("B:G").Copy
  Sheets("BGSOCIAL").Range("B:G").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


 Workbooks.Open FileName:="C:\Users\p100789\Documents\SAP\SAP 
 GUI\text.txt"
 Cells.ClearContents
 ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

 End Sub
```

Comment: Your code deletes all the cells on the sheet `temp`, opens the CSV file, clears the data on columns B to G for that worksheet and tries to copy data from the temp sheet (which you deleted before). Your sheet will always be empty

Comment: @Damian No the CVS file is not necessarily empty I didn't put the code piece before but now I want to use only the temp sheet and the sheet containing my table

Comment: Damian is right. Your sheet will always be empty because your code deletes anything that might be written in the temp file before it can be copied.

Comment: `Sheets("temp").Select
  Cells.Select
  Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp` <-- this code deletes everything from temp sheet

Comment: @Damian I just tried it and in fact I delete the content before my data is exported to temp.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("temp")

        If IsEmpty(.UsedRange) Then
            MsgBox "Empty"
        Else

        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, *Is there a solution of this type but which matches with my Copy/Select code 
- If the sheet is empty, do not select and copy the data

Comment: Someone would have an idea, I beg you, I can't get my code forward.